# how to Import Project in Java plugin in for eclipsed in blackberry

Tags: java, eclipse, blackberry

i have one tool java plugin for eclipsed for Blackberry i want to import

one project but i m not able to import that project can please  post step for importing project in

Blackberry java plugin in eclipsed.

Answer (score 2):

For importing blackberry projects in eclipse, follow the step below.

**File->Import->General->Existing Project into Workspace** then browse for your project folder.

OR

**File->Import->BlackBerry->Import Legacy Blackberry Projects** then browse for your .jdw file.